# How to add a changebar in single lines of an align environment?

Tags: align, changebar

I want to add a changebar to single lines within an align environment. Actually, it does not have to be an align environment, but can be any environment that supports numbered equations and a (simple) way to align several lines.

Do you have a solution for this problem? Please keep in mind that I have to use the changebar package. Thus, \cbstart and \cbend should be used.

Here is what I tried until now:

1. Changebar on whole align works:

```
\cbstart 
\begin{align}
a &=  b + c \\
d &=  e + f \\
g &=  h + i 
\end{align}
\cbend
```

However, here is my first question: Do you know an easy way to shorten the bar to the lines with equations only?

2. As mentioned above I want to achieve that single equations within align can be marked, but changebar within align does not work:

```
\begin{align}
a &=  b + c \\
\cbstart d &=  e + f \cbend \\ 
g &=  h + i 
\end{align}
```

During my test I had several other funny side effects, e.g., a changebar ranging over whole pages that should not have been marked. The same was true for the other environments defined in the amsmath package.

3. The closest I got was with the following combination of equation and array:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lll}
a &=& b + c \\
\cbstart d &=& e + f \cbend \\
g &=& h + i 
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Here of course only one equation is numbered, but I want all three of them numbered.

4. The obvious alternative eqnarray does not work either:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
a &=& b + c \\
\cbstart d &=& e + f \cbend \\
g &=& h + i 
\end{eqnarray}
```

Do you have any suggestions what to do?

Here is the whole code (to obtain the changebars you have to compile at least two times):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\cbstart 
\begin{align}
a &=  b + c \\
d &=  e + f \\
g &=  h + i 
\end{align}
\cbend

\begin{align}
a &=  b + c \\
\cbstart d &=  e + f \cbend \\ 
g &=  h + i 
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lll}
a &=& b + c \\
\cbstart d &=& e + f \cbend \\
g &=& h + i 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{eqnarray}
a &=& b + c \\
\cbstart d &=& e + f \cbend \\
g &=& h + i 
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code for changebar in align]